# In what cases is the `CancellationToken` signaled with Azure Functions triggered on a consumption plan?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, cancellation-token

My question is about the `CancellationToken` passed into C# functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#cancellation-tokens

We have observed that occasionally when we are in the middle of running a function, the `CancellationToken` is raised and causes all our `async` calls to stop. If a `CancellationToken` is signaled, we do expect this behavior, but I have a more general question about what causes this `CancellationToken` to be signaled in the first place. According to the documentation, I am left with a sort of vague feeling of understanding on the topic.

It seems like it just can happen any time the operating system says "it is time to shut down what we are working on". But I have no idea under which conditions this can and will happen when hosting functions within Azure. Does this ever happen as a result of functions running on the consumption plan needs to "scale out" under the hood? If not, what exactly (in the context of hosting within Azure on the consumption plan) causes this to happen?

Further more, should we be passing the `CancellationToken` along to async calls? I feel like the answer is yes, but maybe this is our mistake in the first place. Maybe we aren't supposed to pass the `CancellationToken` along at all, but it would feel so strange.

For a little more context on how we came across this issue/question in the first place:
- We have a `TimerTrigger` function that runs once a day which queues tens of thousands of messages onto an Azure Storage Queue using the `Azure.Storage.Queues` nuget package. 
- We have a `QueueTrigger` function that picks up messages from the queue and makes calls to an HTTP dependency.

What we observed is that our `TimerTrigger` function was failing often after a couple thousand messages, with exceptions along the lines of `TaskCanceledException`. My first guess was that the function was timing out after 10 minutes, but it usually happens only a minute into execution.

My working theory is that after queuing messages begins, the `QueueTrigger` function begins to process them with high levels of parallelization. However, after a certain threshold the underlying infrastructure (ie: the consumption plan VMs) determine that in order to handle the load it should scale out. If this is the case, maybe the functions that were started on the original machine (ie, the `TimerTrigger` function) are signaled to wrap up what they are doing via the `CancellationToken` since the VM is being free'ed up/abandoned.

I realize that the internal workings of Azure are not something that are typically discussed in regards to how functions are scaled, etc. But I would really like to know what exactly is causing my `TimerTrigger`'s `CancellationToken` to be signaled.

For anyone that runs across this issue and wonders how we ended up solving at (at least in the short term): We decided to take our logic in the `TimerTrigger` and refactor into a durable function. So basically the `TimerTrigger` simply kicks off an `OrchestrationTrigger` and we have an `ActivityTrigger` that queues a much smaller number of messages at a time. We call that `ActivityTrigger` from the `OrchestrationTrigger` with a retry policy, which allows the process to complete gracefully even when a `CancellationToken` is signaled in the `ActivityTrigger` function (which does happen about 10-15% of the time, from my initial testing).

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you posted some code. You could be exceeding the memory limits of the Azure function (it's hard to say without seeing some code) and thus causing the function to abruptly terminate.

Comment: Hey @Kane! I'm not able to post the exact code, but if I have some time later today I can come up with something. I will say that I am fairly confident that we are not running out of memory. But this is the type of discussion I was hoping to have. Other than running out of memory, what are the types of things that can cause the Azure Function `CancellationToken` to be signaled, etc...

Comment: @AnthonyIacono were you able to find an answer? We have something really similar - although just a TimerTrigger scheduled to run every 20s and no QueueTriggers. My current working theory is that the function is still running when the next scheduled run time is reached. According to Azure docs, TimerTriggers have a singleton lock meaning only one function instance can be running at once. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger#scheduling 

Also, this doesn't happen on every time, only a handful of times throughout the day.